# C writing/reading memory snapshot to/from Disk

Tags: c, memory-management, file-io, redis

I am implementing my own [Redis](http://redis.io/) in C. I have designed bitmap by allocating sufficient enough memory to hold `n` unsigned longs (say words) and then using word offset and bit offset to set/clear a bit at a position `pos`

```
word_offset = pos / BITS_PER_WORD;
bit_offset = pos % BITS_PER_WORD;
```

Next step is to persist this bitmap by writing it to disk, that can be read back again to restore the bitmap.

As a first and naive approach, I tried to read memory word by word and write this unsigned long to a file. It works but looks ugly, works slow and feels dumb as a bitmap can grow upto 512mb in size.

Moreover, I have to store multiple such bitmaps to a single file.

How can I design an efficient approach to save my data structures to disk. Since it is a learning project, I am avoiding peeking into Redis source code.

Comment: I'm not sure you are right in avoiding looking into Redis source code. You'll learn a lot by glancing into it.

Comment: I ll definitely look into the redis source code, how can I afford to avoid such piece of engineering. I just want to code it first by myself, then I can compare and learn from it.

Comment: But I'm sure your learn more by working in the opposite order: study Redis source code, then code your own "clone". Also, your question is OS specific. If on Linux, read http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/

Answer (score 2):

See [fwrite](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fwrite.html):

```
#include <stdio.h>

size_t fwrite(const void *restrict ptr, size_t size, size_t nitems,
       FILE *restrict stream);
```

> The `fwrite()` function shall write, from the array pointed to by `ptr`, up to `nitems` elements whose size is specified by size, to the stream pointed to by stream. For each object, size calls shall be made to the `fputc()` function, taking the values (in order) from an array of unsigned char exactly overlaying the object. The file-position indicator for the stream (if defined) shall be advanced by the number of bytes successfully written. If an error occurs, the resulting value of the file-position indicator for the stream is unspecified.

The corresponding function for reads is [fread](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fread.html).

If POSIX is the only requirement, use [write](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/write.html):

```
#include <unistd.h>

ssize_t pwrite(int fildes, const void *buf, size_t nbyte,
       off_t offset);
ssize_t write(int fildes, const void *buf, size_t nbyte);
```

> The `write()` function shall attempt to write `nbyte` bytes from the buffer pointed to by `buf` to the file associated with the open file descriptor, `fildes`.

The corresponding function for reads is [read](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/read.html).